# How to set a shortcut for each application in Gnome 3?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, shortcuts

Is it possible to use a shortcut for each application in Gnome3? For instance, in Unity I use Super-1 for the first application in laucher, Super-2 for the second one and so on.

EDIT

The alternative solution I found was to use each application in a separate workspace and set a shortcut for each workspace using using dconf-editor `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have a solution, but another alternative would be to install [THIS "Dash Hotkeys"](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/413/dash-hotkeys/) extension, which is essentially what you asked for. As of testing under 3.4, it also allows you to switch to the running app, say number 6, which hasn't been added to the Dash; so you can switch to anything running as well. To install all you need to do is click the On/Off switch and accept to install on the modal dialog that will pop up.

This was only tested on 3.4.